# how to make scrollable the legends of pie chart ( chart js )

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I have this pie chart with this problems. i have many items and the responsive has not an scroll for show correctly the legends in mobile mode. ¿Is there any solution?

[Show image here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ffSV2.png)

```js
new Chart(document.getElementById("pie-chart"), {
            type: 'pie',
            data: {
            labels: [<?php echo $mostrar_prendas;?>],
            datasets: [{
            label: "Population (millions)",
            backgroundColor: [<?php echo $mostrar_colores;?>],
            data: [<?php echo $mostrar_cantidad;?>]
            }]
            },
            options: {
            title: {
            display: false,
            text: 'Predicted world population (millions) in 2050'
            },
            
            }
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of an HTML legend, this will stay out of the canvas so it will always be viseble and you can style it however you want. Chart.js has a sample on their website with how to implement it: https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/samples/legend/html.html

Live example:

```js
const getOrCreateLegendList = (chart, id) => {
  const legendContainer = document.getElementById(id);
  let listContainer = legendContainer.querySelector('ul');

  if (!listContainer) {
    listContainer = document.createElement('ul');
    listContainer.style.display = 'flex';
    listContainer.style.flexDirection = 'row';
    listContainer.style.margin = 0;
    listContainer.style.padding = 0;

    legendContainer.appendChild(listContainer);
  }

  return listContainer;
};

const htmlLegendPlugin = {
  id: 'htmlLegend',
  afterUpdate(chart, args, options) {
    const ul = getOrCreateLegendList(chart, options.containerID);

    // Remove old legend items
    while (ul.firstChild) {
      ul.firstChild.remove();
    }

    // Reuse the built-in legendItems generator
    const items = chart.options.plugins.legend.labels.generateLabels(chart);

    items.forEach(item => {
      const li = document.createElement('li');
      li.style.alignItems = 'center';
      li.style.cursor = 'pointer';
      li.style.display = 'flex';
      li.style.flexDirection = 'row';
      li.style.marginLeft = '10px';

      li.onclick = () => {
        const {
          type
        } = chart.config;
        if (type === 'pie' || type === 'doughnut') {
          // Pie and doughnut charts only have a single dataset and visibility is per item
          chart.toggleDataVisibility(item.index);
        } else {
          chart.setDatasetVisibility(item.datasetIndex, !chart.isDatasetVisible(item.datasetIndex));
        }
        chart.update();
      };

      // Color box
      const boxSpan = document.createElement('span');
      boxSpan.style.background = item.fillStyle;
      boxSpan.style.borderColor = item.strokeStyle;
      boxSpan.style.borderWidth = item.lineWidth + 'px';
      boxSpan.style.display = 'inline-block';
      boxSpan.style.height = '20px';
      boxSpan.style.marginRight = '10px';
      boxSpan.style.width = '20px';

      // Text
      const textContainer = document.createElement('p');
      textContainer.style.color = item.fontColor;
      textContainer.style.margin = 0;
      textContainer.style.padding = 0;
      textContainer.style.textDecoration = item.hidden ? 'line-through' : '';

      const text = document.createTextNode(item.text);
      textContainer.appendChild(text);

      li.appendChild(boxSpan);
      li.appendChild(textContainer);
      ul.appendChild(li);
    });
  }
};

const options = {
  type: 'doughnut',
  data: {
    labels: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
    datasets: [{
      label: '# of Votes',
      data: [12, 19, 3, 5, 2, 3],
      backgroundColor: ["Red", "Blue", "Yellow", "Green", "Purple", "Orange"],
      borderWidth: 1
    }]
  },
  options: {
    plugins: {
      htmlLegend: {
        // ID of the container to put the legend in
        containerID: 'legend-container',
      },
      legend: {
        display: false,
      }
    }
  },
  plugins: [htmlLegendPlugin]
}

const ctx = document.getElementById('chartJSContainer').getContext('2d');
new Chart(ctx, options);
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="legend-container">

  </div>
  <canvas id="chartJSContainer" width="600" height="400"></canvas>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/Chart.js/3.3.2/chart.js"></script>
</body>
```